# Angular2 Consuming rest api with base url or not

Tags: javascript, angular

I have more of a style question. So I have my services classes with my http calls. What would be best practice in Angular

```
http.get("/api/some-stuff")
```

or

```
http.get("${api.url}"/some-stuff
```

What would be the better approach? I noticed with the first one, I need some sort of proxy and url rewrite on my web server after I build the project.

For the second approach I need some sort of env deployment. But as said. What is best practice here?

Comment: this is more of a design choice personally i would choose the second one as you have only a single point where you change the base url and everythingchanges and usi cli you can have all that env setup easliy

Comment: Before the SOF police closes your question as opinion-based, I just want to let you know that in the first case, you don't need a proxy, an interceptor can d othe trick pretty well !

Comment: Syntax for second code snippet is to use backticks (`\``) instead of double-inverted commas (`"`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just opinion question and i would like to say, that from my point of view the best practice would be to have in memory service wich will handle your rest api uri and:

http.get(urlResolver.getBase() + urlResolver.getYourEntryPoint())